# How to understand the key in python max function

Tags: python, numpy

I have an exemplary code:

```
import numpy as np
x = [np.array(range(10))]
res = max(x, key=np.size)
```

I expect the `res` will be `10`, but in fact

```
>>> res
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Anyone can explain that?

Comment: The example is confusing. The numpy array is in fact the only element inside the python list whose max element is being computed

Comment: @inspectorG4dget It also confuses me. :-) Is that max() always output the original element in its input `arg1`?

Comment: You have a list with a single element. No matter what that element is (or what the key is), it will always be the maximum value of that list. It just happens to be that this element is a numpy array...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example code shows a python list (`x`) which contains one single numpy array with 10 elements. The max of that list (regardless of the key) is that numpy array.

> What does `key` do?

This is a function that computes a value to each element in the list that is different from its representational value. Whichever element has the largest value as computed by this function is the max of the list.

For example:

```
In [109]: L = [str(i) for i in range(20)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [110]: L                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[110]: 
['0',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '10',
 '11',
 '12',
 '13',
 '14',
 '15',
 '16',
 '17',
 '18',
 '19']

In [111]: max(L)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[111]: '9'  # '9' is the lexicographically max string

In [112]: max(L, key=int)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[112]: '19'  # 19 is the numerically max number, int('19') has this value
```

The example you have would have been clearer were it written like this instead:

```
In [106]: L = [np.array(range(i)) for i in range(1, 11)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [107]: L                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[107]: 
[array([0]),
 array([0, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]

In [108]: max(L, key=np.size)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[108]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you are using the range(10), which goes up to 10, but doesn't include the number 10. The way to go here is `x =[np.array(range(11))]`

And to get the max of this, using the numpy documentation, you can use np.amax, which can be done like this: `res = np.amax(x)` and it should work

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html - link for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code.
You initiate NumPy array into Python list.

Variable `x` should be `np.array(range(10))` instead of `[np.array(range(10))]`.

Now `x` is as followed:
`array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

In this case, `max()` function does not need `np.size` because function will search largest value by default. For this example, `key` is not needed. You want to use key if you are using a dictionary. For example:

```
x = {'first': 1, 'second': 5, 'third': 2}
```

If you want `max()` to return key/value with longest key, you'll use it as:

```
max(x.items(), key=len)
```

or if you want the highest value:

```
max(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

With `key`, you specify how do you want `max()` to work.

`res` will have the value `9` because the highest value of `range(10)` is number `9`. To have NumPy array that has the value `10`, you need to use `range(11)` (function is not inclusive).

Comment: I think that the OP is asking for some clarity on how the key function works in general.

Answer (score 1):

**No1. Extra `[]`**

You have an extra `[]` surrounding your array. So in your code, the `max` function is actually only looking at a list of one element containing your `np.array`. Since there is only one element, it will always be the same.

As a test, in the same terminal, type in `x` and notice that it is surrounded by brackets.

Just remove the `[]` from around the array def so it looks like this:
`x = np.array(range(10))`. Or you can modify it to be like the example I'm leaving below.

**No2. Max Key**
The key function allows you to pass the function into a value before checking the maximum. So for example if you had something like this:

```
x = [np.array(range(4), np.array(7)]
res = max(x, key=np.size)
```

Then `res` would be `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`. This is because the program will first run `np.size()` on each element (in this case the two arrays) and then run `max` on those values. So in our example, the `max` function would actually run on `[4,7]`.